# Is decreasing size of delete query a correct way to avoid ORA-01628?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a delete query like:

```
delete from table1 where dataA between Date1 and Date2
```

I receive an error:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01628: max # extents (10100) reached 
for rollback segment.
```

I would like to fix the delete statement by adding

```
AND ROWNUM < 200
```

Is this the correct way to resolve the problem (table contains blob columns — for this reason I suppose rollback segment is small)?

Comment: The correct way is to increase the rollback segment. It should be adjusted so that your largest transaction can fit in it. You should not adjust your transactions to your rollback segment.

Comment: Increasing rollback segment costs money. It is heavy loaded table that can contains sometemis 1Mb in one row. Process of deleting is executed in night time when using of table is more less.

Comment: have you considered partitioning if this is a scheduled delete of old data? e.g. interval partitioning on the date column? that way you can just drop the old partition instead of large deletes. p.s. in your way, you'd have to COMMIT too to release the rollback every 200 rows.

Comment: I should add to @DazzaL's comment that you can only partition in Oracle if you've spent the money on this "extra".

Comment: I am supporting idea that do commit every fixed number of rows. I usually use COMMIT every 1000.

Comment: @DARK_A: committing every n rows actually *increases* the load on the server. You might want to read this: http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:4951966319022

Comment: @user710818: so increasing the rollback segment costs more money than manually reverting "transactions" that went wrong?

Comment: If it's a really huge table, and you absolutely cannot increase the UNDO enough, then you should take a look at [DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_parallel_ex.htm#CHDIJACH).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do data warehouse bulk processing in Oracle and your method is perfectly fine.  I would like to tell the dba to say hey add a ton of rollback/tmp space so we never run into this... but as with many clients... resources are many times outside of our control.

What i do in any repetitive delete operation that you just want to delete in chunks is the following (Oracle Pl/sql example but will port to any language)  Keep in mind this solution is only for a delete from without conditional where expression(your example)...  if you had a where condition i would recommend fetching rowid's/keys into array first in bulk and the looping deleting in chunks...

```
//psuedo code
Create procedure (iCommit In Integer) 
   Loop
      Delete From Table where rownum < iCommit + 1;
      if SQL%ROWCOUNT < iCommit then
         exit loop;
      end if
      // incremental commit
      commit;
   End Loop;
   // final commit
   commit;
)
```