# How to optimize delete query (with subquery) in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I have query like:

```
 delete from tableA 
 where tableA.fk in (select id 
                     from tableB 
                     where tableB.column1='somevalue' 
                     and tableB.date between date1 and date2)
   ;
```

Table tableB contains near 100,000,000 records. So

```
select id 
from tableB 
where  tableB.column1='somevalue' 
and tableB.date between date1 and date2
```

returns near 1,000,000 records. As result - delete doesn't work at all - problem with size of rollback segment. I cannot increase size of segment.

How it can be executed?

Comment: You can create a new table with the data you need (ie the inverse of your select), drop the old table and finally rename the new table.

Comment: Can you delete the rows day by day, instead of using a date range?

Comment: I think may be join instead of subquery will be faster...

Comment: The issue is you are trying to delete a massive set of rows, this is inherently slow (especially with indexes)

Comment: filling the rollback segment is not a performance problem, it has to do with the amount of data involved in the transaction

Comment: q1-how long does it take to return the select query? q2-how many indices in tableA?

Comment: "*I cannot increase size of segment*". Why? If you need to have such a transaction you should size your rollback segment approriatly. You should adjust your transaction to your rollback segment, but your rollback segment to your transaction. (btw it's called UNDO segment since Oracle 9i, not rollback segment).

Comment: how many rows in table A will be affected?  If 1-1 correlation with B, then 1mm rows, but maybe much more?  replace "delete" with "select count(1)" in the first statement, what do u get?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is decreasing size of delete query a correct way to avoid ORA-01628?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14123726/is-decreasing-size-of-delete-query-a-correct-way-to-avoid-ora-01628)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are filling the rollback segment it is probably because the amount of data involved in your transaction.

I'd split into several chunks and commit each of them, something like :

```
 delete from tableA where tableA.fk in (
    select id from (
            select id from tableB where 
                tableB.column1='somevalue' and tableB.date between date1 and date2 and id in (select distinct fk from tableA.fk)

        )
        where rownum < XXXX 
    )
```

give XXXX the value you want (10000) or whatever, and then loop executing this statement and don't forget to commit in each iteration.

You have to loop until the delete statement returns 0 (number of affected rows).

**UPDATED QUERY**
As noticed, this will not give the best performance, but will solve the rollback segment problem

Hope it helps

Comment: this is gross inefficient.

Comment: it could be made more efficient by changing the subselect but if the problem is that it is filling the rollback segment it has to be done in smaller transactions (not one bigger as you suggested and I didn't downrated)

Comment: Segmenting it out is not going to save any time.  The same amount of work ends up being done, this is why I down voted your answer.

Comment: You may have not read the full question : "problem with size of rollback segment. I cannot increase size of segment." It is not a performance problem. I just pointed the idea of doing it in batches which will solve the problem.

Comment: even if it was purely just the size of the segment, you have still suggested an improper solution to the problem.  My speculation is that OP would come back and say "This is slow, why"

Comment: The performance of query is not important. Problem that query should always work - problem with rollback segment size.

Comment: As I said several times he is asking for a way to be able to delete the data. It will always be possible to do it faster, but that is not the question here. @user710818, please try this approach, I am sure it will help you.

Comment: but re-written query seems doesn't work. If it will return the same set for subquery? In this case I should also delete from tableB!

Comment: But I cannot do it - for referential constraints!

Answer (score 6):

Deletions are the most expensive operation in terms of rollback (undo) space usage, because we have to store the whole deleted row (whereas to undo an insert statement simply requires the database to store the rowid).  The simplest solution to your problem would be to add more files to the UNDO tablespace.

But you say

> "I cannot increase size of segment"

This is slightly surprising,  After all, disk is cheap these days.  Perhaps you have an angry DBA who you are scared to approach?  But your DBA is failing in their duty to provision the database so it can be maintained;  frankly, it is stupid to have a VLDB (a hundred million row table counts as such, even in these days of petabytes and zettabytes) with insufficient Undo space.

But if you won't beard the mintotaur in the data centre all you can do is change your code.  Here is one option.  Given this  ...

```
select id 
from tableB 
where  tableB.column1='somevalue' 
and tableB.date between date1 and date2
```

... returns one million rows, and hence tries to delete too many rows from `tableA`,  you could try a sub-query which returns fewer rows.  For the purposes on the exercise I am assuming the range specified by `date1` to `date2` is thirty days: you will need to adjust the following code accordingly.

```
for i in 1..10 loop
    delete from tableA 
     where tableA.fk in (select id 
                         from tableB 
                         where tableB.column1='somevalue' 
                         and tableB.date between date1 + (3 * (i-1)) and  date1 + (3 * i)
       ;
    commit;
end loop
```

This will simply split the select into ten three-day chunks.  It will take *much longer* to do it this way, but it shouldn't blow the Undo tablespace.

Answer (score 3):

what you want to do is this:

```
create table foo_bar  
as select  *  
from tableA   
where tableA.fk not in (select id from tableB where 
 tableB.column1='somevalue' and tableB.date between date1 and date2);
```

followed by a truncate + delete of the original table

```
truncate tableA  
drop tableA
```

Then rename `foo_bar` to `tableA`

```
alter table foo_bar  rename to tableA
```

Of note, make sure to disable all indexes.

**COMMENTS**

> I cannot drop table. It is always in use.

You most certainly can.  You need to hide the table behind a `view` which is just a virtual function and/or set aside some maintenance time because you cannot blow data away while you are inserting.  Now a more typical approach is to push this data into a `materialized view` that will operate as a `fact table`.  This allows you to modify the base table (tableA) at any time without fear of hurting the user queries against the materialized view.

Use of the `nologging` parameter will reduce the amount of rollback being utilized.  You cannot recover a materialized view built with `nologging`

Comment: I cannot drop table. It is always in use.

Comment: @user710818 I have replied to your comment in my answer.

Comment: If deleting 1/10th of the data fills the rollback segment, inserting 9/10th of the data into another table will surely also fill it.

Comment: @richardtz do you know how materialized views work? If you supply the `nologging` parameter that is a moot point.  I suppose I will make that more clear in my answer.

Comment: @Woot4Moo, you didn't mention nologging until now, but what you are saying is not true. NOLOGGING afects redo logs and has very little  to do with the undo segments (or rollback segments).

Comment: @richardtz and how exactly can you undo if you have no redo or rollback?  This is why you cannot recover nologging operations.

Comment: Redo is for recovery after commiting a transaction. Undo is for rollback before commiting a transaction. You cannot recover nologging operations because there is no redo stored for them, but it doesn't mean you can rollback them before commiting.

Comment: It is true that CTAS is a technique which doesn't generate UNDO: therefore it is a potential solution.  However, there's more to the process than you have listed e.g. indexes, constraints, privileges.  Managing this requires a fair amount of DBA experience, if only to have cojones to run it in production.

Comment: @APC sure.  I expect that OP has someone they can reach out to a bit more deeply, as I myself am not a "real" DBA