# Why Oracle stuck after few deletes?

Tags: oracle, cycle

I have an application that do like:

```
delete from tableA where columnA='somevalue' and rownum<1000
```

In cycle like:

```
 while(deletedRows>0) {
    begin tran
    deletedRows = session ... "delete from tableA where columnA='somevalue' 
    and rownum<1000"....
    commit tran

}
```

It runs few times (each deleting takes near 20 seconds) and after hungs for long time
Why? Does it possible to fix?
Thanks.

---

The reason why the deletes are run in a loop rather than as a single SQL statement is lack of rollback space.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14143510/146325) for more info.

Comment: Can you specify a bit more the "environment"? e.g., are there indexes defined on that table, constraints, triggers etc.

Comment: Ask your DBA what your database session is doing at the point where you think it is hanging - they might be able to guide you.

Comment: Do **NOT** delete in a loop, that is slower and uses more resources than deleting everything in a single transaction.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - I've linked to a related question which explains why the OP is using a loop.

Comment: @apc: I still believe this is a bad workaround. The rollback segment should be sized for the transactions. Not the transactions to the rollback segment.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - I agree, and that's the point I made in my answer on that thread. However we have all found ourselves in situations where the DBA is unapproachable for one reason or another. It is often quicker to bung in a technical kludge than it is to resolve the political problem. Sad but true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time the query scans the table from the beginning. So, it scans the zones where there are no rows to delete(`columnA='somevalue'`). They are more and more far away from the first block of the table.

If the table is big and there would be no `columnA='somevalue'` the query will take the time to verify all the row for your condition.

What you can do is to make an index on `columnA`. In this case the engine will *know* faster where are the rows with that condition(search on index is exponential time faster).

Another possibility, if you are in a concurent system, is that someone updated a row that you ar trying to delete, but doesn't commited the transaction, so the row is locked.

Answer (score 1):

You probably run into many different issues. As you are saying that database hungs the main reason is that your database is hitting **ORA-00257 Archiver error**.

Every delete produces a redo vector, all redos are then downloaded into an archive log. When archivelog space is exahausted your session hang and remain stuck until someone frees the space.
Usually your DBA has a job that run an archivelog backup every hour (this might be any couple of hours, or every 5 mins, depending by the database workload, etc...) and after the backup has done all sessions go ahead correctly.

Depending by the database configuration, from the client point of view, you might not see the error but just have the behaviour described where you session waits until the space is freed.

In term of design, I agree with other users that a DELETE in a loop is not  a good idea. It could be interesting to know why you are trying to do this loop instead a single DELETE statement.

Comment: I don't think the OP has sufficient visibility of the database to know what's happening.  Therefore I think it's more likely that when they say database hangs what they mean is their session is frozen.

Comment: I agree, but any developer should know how the database they're using works. If I plan to delete a billion of recods I have also to plan, or at least to think, that I will produce a tons of redo entries and I could double check with my DBA if the target database/system might experience any issue for my operations. Definitely developer ought to know how to work with the target database and database principles.

Comment: Definitely.  Also everybody should eat their greens and take thirty mins of exercise each day.